# Caching File in a class variable in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails application I need to query a binary file database on each page load. The query is read only. The file size is 1.4 MB. I have two questions:

1) Does it make sense to cache the `File` object in a class variable?

```
def some_controller_action    
    @@file ||= File.open(filename, 'rb')
    # binary search in @@file
end
```

2) Will the cached object be shared across different requests in the same rails process?

Comment: How do you query the binary file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does make sense. The limitation of this, however, is that if you spawn multiple procsesses for your app, each process will have to cache the 1.4 MB. So the answer to your second question is yes but it will not be shared across multiple processes.

Answer (score 5):

If you use a constant in your class, aka

```
FILE = File.read(filename, 'rb').read
```

so it gets evaluated at application load time. The fork will happen afterwards, so it will be in the shared memory.

Comment: Good idea, thank you. My only concern here is that it would read the file on each app initialization (rails c, in tests etc). What I wanted is a lazy loading of the file, only when it's first accessed.

Comment: You can't have both the cake and eat it (it's a lie anyway), but you could make a method that uses the constant in production mode and lazy-loads otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, good point about the cakes. I think the idea is getting a bit over-architected. Thanks, anyway.